# HtmlAgilityPack select Node return all Node from document

Tags: asp.net, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I want to scrap data from a website when select node from a node using class All Element selected from document

this is my code..

```
  var baseUri = new Uri("http://www.coupondunia.in/flipkart");
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        doc.Load(client.OpenRead(baseUri));
        HtmlNodeCollection div = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'detail-coupons') and contains(@class,'inner')] ");   
        foreach (HtmlNode item in div)
        {
            var Linksx = item.SelectSingleNode("//a[contains(@class,'emptyAnchorCouponPage couponTitle couponTitle_inplaceEdit clickableCoupon')]");
             var Links = item.SelectNodes("//a[contains(@class,'couponTitle') and contains(@class,'emptyAnchorCouponPage') and contains(@class,'couponTitle_inplaceEdit') and contains(@class,'clickableCoupon')]");          
        }
```

In `Links` and `Linkx` return multiple records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To tell `HtmlAgilityPack` that your XPath scope is limited to current `item` you need to add a dot/period (`.`) at the beginning of the XPath :

```
foreach (HtmlNode item in div)
{
    var Linksx = item.SelectSingleNode(".//a[contains(@class,'emptyAnchorCouponPage couponTitle couponTitle_inplaceEdit clickableCoupon')]");
    var Links = item.SelectNodes(".//a[contains(@class,'couponTitle') and contains(@class,'emptyAnchorCouponPage') and contains(@class,'couponTitle_inplaceEdit') and contains(@class,'clickableCoupon')]");          
}
```

Otherwise the XPath scope considered is the entire `HtmlDocument`.